# Discord.py Command Prefix Not Calling Out Commands?

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to figure this out forever now, but it seems that my discord.py command prefix for my bot does not work. Currently, here is my code:

```
players = {}

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="with your words!"))
    called_once_an_hour.start()

@client.command()
async def test():
    await client.send('test')

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def leave(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    await voice_client.disconnect()

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.server
    voice_client = client.voice_client_in(server)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMw-9mXfccY')
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
    print(f"Playing Are you winning son in server voice client: {voice_client}")
```

First client command was mainly for debugging purposes, but its just never called out.
I also think I already have all the necessary imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test command needs to look like:

```
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

I can run this successfully with `!test`

The context is passed by default, `pass_context = True` is no longer necessary.

See the commands docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the reply. Although it seems to work for you, it doesn't seem to be for me. Perhaps something in my current coding is interfering with my command prefixes? I can send the whole coding block if you would like to see whats wrong

Comment: Here is exactly what I am running: https://pastebin.com/86FwTmQ2, I would like to note that the test command is the only command that will work here.  Wherever you copied this code form is using the pre-rewrite version of discord.py, so you will have to modernize it if you want it to work.